# How do I set the theme layout from within a module in PyroCMS?

Tags: pyrocms

I'm doing

```
        $this->template
            ->set_breadcrumb(lang('stuff'), 'stuff')
            ->set_breadcrumb($col->title)
            ->set_layout('questions')
            ->set('title', $col->title)
            ->build('view', $this->data);
```

But my `questions` layout file in my `my_theme` folder.

How do I specify the layout directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question changed while I was answering it so now I am confused. This is correct, it previously wasn't.

[PyroCMS Template Library docs](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/developers/tools/template-library#setlayoutlayoutname)

The location is `addons/<default or shared_addons>/themes/<theme>/views/layouts/` and the `questions.html` layout should be set in there, right next to its buddy `default.html`.

You can of course skip all of this and just make a layout that has the same name as the module. So, remove the `set_layout()` method entirely and you've already completed your task.